# Switching job on EU blue card in Germany

Tags: visa, germany, immigration, eu-citizens, indian-citizens

I worked as Software Developer on EU Blue Card in Germany for 8 months. On green paper my company name was written as well. I wanted to switch job and Rathaus allowed me to switch and gave me new green paper with new company's name on it.
My previous employment ended on October and new joining is after 2 months, I want to go to India (home country) for this 2 months period. I haven't registered for unemployment for the 2 months, as I am not eligible for unemployment benefits as of now.
Would I run into any trouble while coming back?
Thanks

Comment: I am in a similar situation, would like to know as I have a job offer in hand, I would like to know if I should resign first or get permission from Foreign Department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will cause no problem for periods up to

- 6 months, as a general rule (**§ 51(1)(7) AufenthG**)
- 12 months, for EU Blue Card holders (**§ 51 (10) AufenthG**)

For any longer period, permission must be granted by the foreigners authority.

---

> **Section 51 AufenthG
>
> Termination of lawful residence; continued validity of restrictions**
> (1) The residence title shall expire in the following cases:
> ...
>
> > 7. if the foreigner leaves the federal territory and fails to re-enter it **within six months** or within a longer period set by the foreigners authority,
>
> ...
> 10) By way of derogation from subsection 1, no. 7, the period for the **EU Blue Card** and the temporary residence permits pursuant to Sections 30, 32, 33 or 36 issued to dependants of EU Blue Card holders **shall be twelve months**. The same shall apply to the permanent settlement permit of a foreigner who has resided lawfully in the federal territory for at least 15 years and to the permanent settlement permit of a spouse cohabiting with the foreigner if he is 60 years of age or older.
> ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Act on the Residence, Economic Activity and Integration of Foreigners in the Federal Territory Residence Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0927)